# printing last company in the excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel, tcpdf

I have done a program using PHPExcel and TCPDF on PHP. where I can select companies listed in excel file according to column that they are located.
I am tracking companies between already defined columns and between rows that I can scan till "next company's name". So that I can print them out in the screen.

I upload a screenshot how my excel file looks like...[image]

after I retrieve the data from excel file it looks like 
[image]

However, when I select last company since there is no "next company", it doesn't return result; on the contrary it gives an error.

**my question:** how can I control "last company" and print it out like the others. I couldn't put an exceptional condition for last one.

related part of my code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $selected_val = $_POST['my_select'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
        $only_row = explode('.',$selected_val);
        //echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val. "<br />";  // Displaying Selected Value
        //echo "selected row value :".$only_row[1]. "<br />"; this shows selected company's row number
        for($i=0; $i< $count; $i++)
        {
            if ($comp[$i][2]== $only_row[1])
            { 
                $info_end=($comp[$i+1][2]-1);// here table ends before the next company's name  begins  

            }

        }
    }   
    else{error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);}    
    $rowCompanyInfoStart = $only_row[1]+2;
    $rowCompanyInfoEnd = $info_end;
    $colCompanyInfoStart = 'C';
    $colCompanyInfoEnd = 'M';
```

PS: it would be appreciated if you can give a clear answer.

If something is unclear on the question, please let me know.

Comment: There are too many unknowns in the code you have shared to give more than a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you got to do is a test on `$i`, because you can't access `$comp[$i+1][2]-1` when `$i = $count-1`.

So to do something different if this is the last line :

```
for($i=0; $i< $count; $i++) {
    if ($comp[$i][2]== $only_row[1]) {
        // line found
        if($i == ($count - 1)) {
            // what you want to do on last line... 
        } else { 
            // what to do normally
            $info_end=($comp[$i+1][2]-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! thanks alot ...this is what i was asking about

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Random
here is my full solution with exception for the last company

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $selected_val = $_POST['my_select'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable

            $only_row = explode('.',$selected_val);
            //echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val. "<br />";  // Displaying Selected Value
            //var_dump($only_row);
            //echo "selected row value :".$only_row[1]. "<br />";

            for($i=0; $i< $count; $i++) {
         if ($comp[$i][2]== $only_row[1]) {

           // line found

               if($i == ($count - 1)) {

                    // what you want to do on last line... 

                            $info_end=($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow());              
                    }

               else { 

            $info_end=($comp[$i+1][2]-1);
        }
    }
}
        }
```